# Assignment Loop carriage return

Tags: c#, loops, carriage-return

I have an assignment in my C# class that I am confused on. Here is the assignment below. My question is how to implement the carriage return? It seems like using /r resets to the beginning of the line... I was going to use string.empty in a while loop, but I can't tell by the instructions if there is a way to get the desired result by using the carriage return. I feel like I am looking way to into this. Any thoughts?

> Let's take a moment to get our program to do something. Modify your program to:
>   ● Prompt the user for their name
>   ● Store the input string into a variable named str01.
>   ● Output a greeting to the console using the string stored in str01. (ex. "Hello, Ethel!")
>   ● Keep prompting the user to enter a name.
>   ● If they enter an empty string (a simple carriage return), then drop out of the loop with an appropriate message (ex. "See you next time!").

```
class App01
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    string str01;
    for(;;)
    {
      Console.Write ("Enter your name -");
      str01 = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Hello '{0}'", str01);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a `while loop` that should do the same actions, until the `str01 variable` is eqaul to a `carriage return`.

Comment: place a break point after your `ReadLine()`.  Run and press `Enter`.  Look at the value of `str01`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks):

> The ReadLine method reads a **line** from the standard input stream..
>
> A **line** is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a carriage return (hexadecimal 0x000d), a line feed (hexadecimal 0x000a), or the value of the Environment.NewLine property. **The returned string does not contain the terminating character(s).**

If no characters are entered in and we just hit the carriage return, we just get <strike>the carriage return</strike> an empty string. A line is the sequence of characters **up to** the terminating character. In this case the carriage return.

So to address your concern, the desired result by the assignment definition is to just check if the line read into `str01` is empty and display `See you next time!` if it is.